# Obtener todas las coincidencias dado un valor de un arreglo de objetos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que quiero es que en el siguiente arreglo cuando se ingrese un valor en `firstname` me traiga todos los arreglos con ese valor pero con su `lastname` en un arreglo:

```
     var persons = [
       {firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
       {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
       {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"},
       {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
       {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Freeman"},
       {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
       {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Summer"},
       {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Doe"}
                   ];

          /*Loop*/
```

Y que me los traiga parecido de la siguiente manera (de cualquier manera) y lo haría para todos los valores de `firstname` en el arreglo:

```
   result = 'Jayne'{"Cobb","Freeman","Summer","Doe"}
```

Mis avances:

```
var dict = { };
personas.forEach(function (obj) {
    if (!dict[obj.firstname])
        dict[obj.firstname] = [];
    dict[obj.firstname].push(obj.lastname);
});
```

Comment: Hola Godelo, bienvenido a SOes, ¿nos podrías mostrar segmentos de código de lo que has intentado hasta el momento? Con esto será más sencillo darte una respuesta y ayudarte a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: `var dict = {};
            personas.forEach(function (obj) {
                if (!dict[obj.firstname])
                dict[obj.firstname] = [];
            dict[obj.firstname].push(obj.lastname);
           });`

Comment: @Godeolo tienes que ser para un elemento o para todos?

Comment: para todos pero no puedo utilizar ES6

Comment: @Godeolo por que no puedes? que te impide

Comment: las condiciones del proyecto

Answer (score 1):

```js
var people = [
       {firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
       {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
       {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"},
       {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
       {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Freeman"},
       {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
       {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Summer"},
       {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Doe"}
];

var name = 'Jayne';

var matches = people
  .filter(x => x.firstname === name)
  .map(x => x.lastname);

var result = { [name]: matches };

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
     var persons = [
       {firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
       {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
       {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"},
       {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
       {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Freeman"},
       {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
       {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Summer"},
       {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Doe"}
                   ];


var result= persons.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let { firstname, lastname } = item;
  acc[firstname] = acc[firstname] || [];
  acc[firstname].push(lastname);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```